# dax measure to show group total on every row

Tags: dax

I would like to have dax measure that will fill the TotalProduct column like on the picture below:
[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3ZTs.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
TotalProductAllYears:=
CALCULATE(
    [TotalProduct]
    ,ALL( DimDate[Year] )
)
```

Replace DimDate[Year] with the appropriate reference to your date dimension.

ALL() strips context from the field(s) referenced in it. We remove context only from the [Year] field here. The context on [ProductName] is unaffected.